# Cómo quitar espacios en blanco y al mismo tiempo pasar a mayúscula

Tags: javascript

Me sale que se haga `toUpperCase` y también espacios en blanco pero como hago para que sean los dos, que nada mas escribir en el campo de texto me convierta a mayúscula y quite espacios?

```js
document.getElementById('campoNombre').onkeyup = sanear;
function sanear(){
    let contenido        = document.getElementById('campoNombre').value;
    let contenidoSaneado = contenido.toUpperCase();
    let contenidoSinEspacios = contenido.replace(' ', '');

    document.getElementById('campoNombre').value = contenidoSaneado;
    document.getElementById('campoNombre').value = contenidoSinEspacios;

}
```

Answer (score 7):

estabas llamando mal al evento **onkeyup**, te dejo el ejemplo de como deberia ser.

```js
document.getElementById("campoNombre").addEventListener('keyup', sanear);


function sanear(e) {
  let contenido = e.target.value;
  e.target.value = contenido.toUpperCase().replace(" ", "");
}
```

```html
<input id="campoNombre" type="text">
```

Los metodos se pueden concatenar y secuencialmente se van a ejecutar.

Comment: El problema no es cómo estaba asociando el evento, sino que estaba aplicando el segundo método sobre la variable original, en vez de aplicarlo sobre la variable que tiene el resultado del primer método

Answer (score 0):

Mi respuesta es para dar una opción más para ti y tenga un abanico de opciones, en mi ejemplo use el `trim()`, seria lo mismo en este caso que hacer `.replace(" ", "");` el cual fue sugerido por el colega @Facundo Fernandez.

```js
document.getElementById("campoNombre").addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {

  let nombre = e.target.value;
  e.target.value = nombre.toUpperCase().trim();

});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="campoNombre">
```